# Gulp: dest path relative to src

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug

#### Folder constructor:

- project

  - src

    - jade

      - index.jade
  - subProjectA

    - src

      - jade

        - index.jade
    - subProjectB

      - src

        - jade

          - index.jade
      - subProjectC

        - src

          - jade

            - index.jade

---

#### My expect dest:

- project

  - index.html
  - subProjectA

    - index.html
    - subProjectB

      - index.html
      - subProjectC

        - index.html

#### My gulpfile.js:

```
// ...
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    gulp.src(['*.jade'])
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./../../'))
```

Answer (score -1):

[Nodejs path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) has lots of utilities methods that can help. It seems like either [relative](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) or [resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) can do the work for you. Once you have your path fragments right, you can compose them using [join](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) and pass the result to dst.